# How can I open an url after close selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a special problem. I made a software in java, what strore informations from a website. But this website shows this data, just if I click a button. It's a simple webdriver problem, but I can click a button only 10 times. It's a very big problem form me, and I cant't do this. :D 
The site counts my clicks, if I reach ten clicks, it tells me, I should login. But, it possible to login only with facebook or google account. I don't want to login with facebook or google. 
The solution is, I have to close the browser, and I have to reopen that. How can I do this:

```
driver.close();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Okay, but every time when I use this formula, the java code opens a new webdriver. What is the solutin of this problem? Maybe driver.quit(); ??
No!!
If I quit the driver, I can't create a new driver. So, when I open the 321654th webpage, I have 321654/10 webdriver among Windows tasks.

What is the real solution?

Comment: If I were to guess, you are probably breaking the Terms of Service of this site because you are scraping the site and/or interacting with it using a bot. That's probably part of the reason why this click protection is there in the first place. What site is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with refresh your page instead of close. Use below code:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting cookies?  You might also then have to refresh the page.

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
```